# how to deal with a hands off boss?

Tags: communication

I just started a new job in a new field after completing my graduate degree. I'm working in a startup of about 20 people, and my team - research - is three people.

While we have weekly status meetings, my boss is hands off in his management style. My latest project is model creation and an error analysis on data my boss gave me. That was the extent of the description i was given.  I took off running on creating a model, but when I asked him how he wanted the errors presented, he changed the overall scope and definition of the problem.  This was a clarification that I could have gotten much sooner, but it never occurred to me to ask. Generally, if i know of a way to proceed, i will and not ask for more direction.  In this case, I had enough leeway to hang myself a bit.

I've been under a boss previously that would be hands off until the end when they would comment on how poor my process was, and I constantly felt like I was under performing. My projects are only going to become more complex, and I'm worried I'm going to fall into old patterns.  How should I communicate with him so that I make sure I perform well AND mesh with my boss?

Comment: "I've been under a boss previously" Do not take you opinions and evaluations into the next job. What happened with person X is not necessarily going to happen with person Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your boss is hands off, then the responsibility for asking for direction when you need direction is more than ever fully yours.

I ask for direction when:

1. I don't have a clue how to proceed to go forward, and I need a hint. I don't care how silly, stupid or ignorant I look, just give me da damn hint :)
2. I have worked out roughly a way to proceed, and I want to make sure that I am on the right track. If I had to make assumptions when I started, then it's a good time for me to make sure that these are assumptions that they can live with.
3. I have had situations where either I misinterpreted what they wanted or they miscommunicated what they wanted.
4. I have had situations where I interpreted correctly what they wanted but they changed they mind the minute they realized that they were getting what they wanted. No harm, no foul if you ask early enough in the game. There is no point to winning a particular game when you were supposed to play a different game :)
5. I have worked out a way to proceed, and I want to make sure that my approach is the best possible approach.
6. I am well on my way to finishing the task, and I want a sanity check. Because I don't need anyone anyone lavishing my completed task with a "This is NOT what I wanted!" I just don't need that kind of praise :)

You are not asking for direction because you need supervision, you are asking for direction because you need to **coordinate** with your management and co-workers to get the task done efficiently in the way they want it done and according to their specifications. Asking for direction when you need direction is not a weakness in my book - it's a strength.

Answer (score 0):

Put milestones in the project so your boss and anyone else can add inputs:
Design review
Daily or weekly status (even by mail)
Work in small iterations that you can present